# how to read number of lines in a text file from server?

Tags: android, webview

i have one text file in fileden. Link is here...

http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/11/16/3367367/trailers.txt

i want to count number of lines in this text file .. i will update this text file further..

I may add number of lines to this text file or i may remove number of lines. Based on this

number of lines i display images in my app. If i have two lines i should display two images..

If i i have four lines of text then i will display four images in my App..

Any idea share to me here...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: read this answer, \n means new line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749655/how-to-count-lines-in-file-txt-android

Comment: thank you for your reply here i didn't get proper idea with this link..