# read a specifc line in large text file in android

Tags: android, eclipse, text

I want to read a specific line large text file up to 60 MB java. I am search from last three days but found no better result then use a loop with buffered reader.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

}
```

But it takes to much time. How can I access specific line from a text file in android.

Comment: do you have some filters for that ? like some text to identify the line or as Stacks28 mentioned, line number ?

Comment: yes of course. I have the line number

Comment: You can refer to this link for acheiving the task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749655/how-to-count-lines-in-file-txt-android

Comment: It also using a loop to get results, same as i done. Its slow.