# how do i get a single line from a txt file on android studio

Tags: java, android

My Code to get file content:

```
private String readTxt(){

            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text);

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int i;
            try {
                i = inputStream.read();
                while (i != -1)
                {
                   byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                   i = inputStream.read();
                }
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
        }
```

but i want only one specific line on that file to be extracted.

Comment: "one specific line" - which?

Comment: line number 3 for example from a text file in my res directory
text.txt: 
line1
line2
line3

Comment: possible duplicate of [read a specifc line in large text file in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267609/read-a-specifc-line-in-large-text-file-in-android)

Comment: The answers on the duplicate aren't very good.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BufferedReader` instead of `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

```
String readLine(int line) throws IOException {

    InputStream in   = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    try {

        String lineStr  = null;
        int currentLine = 0;

        while ((lineStr = r.readLine()) != null) {

            if (currentLine++ == line) {
                return lineStr;
            }

        }
    } finally {
        if (r != null) {
            r.close();
        }
    }

    throw new IOException("line " + line + " not found");
}
```